# QStyledItemDelegate problem in paint function

Tags: c++, qt

I have `QListView` and `DelegateClass` : `QStyledItemDelegate`.
In paint function I want to catch Mouse over state. When I test my code in windows if `(oOption.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver)` condition works fine but in linux does not catch this state. What can be the difference between linux and windows `QStyle::StateMouseOver`?

```
if (oOption.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver)
{
    // does not enter in linux 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the problem but actually couldn't make it work even in Windows. To have it working properly I had to enable [mouse tracking](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop) first on the `QListView`:

```
theQListView->setMouseTracking(true);
```

Maybe you have platform-conditioned such property?